# IOI Qualifier INOI task 2

Tags: algorithm

I can't figure out how to solve question 2 in the following link in an efficient manner:
http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2012/inoi2012/inoi2012-qpaper.pdf

Comment: Why not just use the trivial `O(n^2)` algorithm?

Comment: Because that would not complete the 2nd subtask (1 <= N <= 200000) in the required time (2 seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in On log n) time.  (Or linear if you really care to.)  First, pad the input array out to the next power of two using some really big negative number.  Now, build an interval tree-like data structure; recursively partition your array by dividing it in half.  Each node in the tree represents a subarray whose length is a power of two and which begins at a position that is a multiple of its length, and each nonleaf node has a "left half" child and a "right half" child.

Compute, for each node in your tree, what happens when you add `0,1,2,3,...` to that subarray and take the maximum element.  Notice that this is trivial for the leaves, which represent subarrays of length 1.  For internal nodes, this is simply the maximum of the left child with length/2 + right child.  So you can build this tree in linear time.

Now we want to run a sequence of `n` queries on this tree and print out the answers.  The queries are of the form "what happens if I add `k,k+1,k+2,...n,1,...,k-1` to the array and report the maximum?"

Notice that, when we add that sequence to the whole array, the break between n and 1 either occurs at the beginning/end, or smack in the middle, or somewhere in the left half, or somewhere in the right half.  So, partition the array into the `k,k+1,k+2,...,n` part and the `1,2,...,k-1` part.  If you identify all of the nodes in the tree that represent subarrays lying completely inside one of the two sequences but whose parents either don't exist or straddle the break-point, you will have O(log n) nodes.  You need to look at their values, add various constants, and take the maximum.  So each query takes O(log n) time.