# Speeding up LCS algorithm for graph construction

Tags: performance, algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

Referencing 2nd question from [INOI 2011](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2013/inoi2013/inoi2013-qpaper.pdf):

> N people live in Sequence Land. Instead of a name, each person is identified by a sequence of integers, called his or her id. Each id is a sequence with no duplicate elements. Two people are said to be each other’s relatives if their ids have at least K elements in common. The extended family of a resident of Sequence Land includes herself or himself, all relatives, relatives of relatives, relatives of relatives of relatives, and so on without any limit.
>   Given the ids of all residents of Sequence Land, including its President, and the number K, find the number of people in the extended family of the President of Sequence Land.
>
> For example, suppose N = 4 and K = 2. Suppose the President has id (4, 6, 7, 8) and the other three residents have ids (8, 3, 0, 4), (0, 10), and (1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 8). Here, the President is directly related to (8, 3, 0, 4), who in turn is directly related to (1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 8). Thus, the President’s extended family consists of everyone other than (0, 10) and so has size 3.
>
> Limits: 1 <= n <= 300 & 1 <= K <= 300. Number of elements per id: 1-300

Currently, my solution is as follows:

1. For every person, compare his id to all other id's using an algorithm same as LCS, it can be edited to stop searching if k elements aren't there etc. etc. to improve it's average case performance.  **Time complexity = O(n^2*k^2)**
2. Construct adjacency list using previous step result.
3. Use BFS. Output results

But the overall time complexity of this algorithm is not good enough for the second subtask. I googled around a little bit, and found most solutions to be similar to that of mine, and not working for larger subtask. The only thing close to a good solution was this one -> [Yes, this question has been asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081979/ioi-qualifier-inoi-task-2). The reason I'm asking essentially the same question again is that that solution is really tough to work with and implement. Recently, a friend of mine told me about a much better solution he read somewhere.

Can someone help me create a better solution ?

Even pointers to better solution would be great.

Comment: You don't need LCS if the lists of integers are sorted -- in that case, just a linear-time list merge ("intersection") will do the trick.  Separately, which LCS algorithm are you using that takes O(k^2) time to determine whether two lists have an LCS of k or more?  It seems likely that you're omitting a factor for the lengths of the lists, which are not bounded by any function of k.

Comment: Also that link doesn't seem to be to a related problem.